# Delete only certain Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spread sheet which in column A I place a Y when I invoice the line. I wish at the end of the month to delete ALL Rows with a Y in column A only, then move all rows up so there are no blank lines in the spread sheet. How is the quickest way to do this as I have 26 separate spread sheets I need to do it in every end of month?

Answer (score 1):

*You need this VBA (Macro) to delete all rows which has Y in Column A, across Worksheets.*

```
Option Explicit


Sub DeleteRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In Worksheets

lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr To 1 Step -1

 If ws.Range("A" & i) = "Y" Then
    ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
 Next i
 Next ws

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 MsgBox "Rows Deleted"

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Copy & Paste this code as Standard module.
- Search String "Y" to delete Rows across Sheets is editable.