# Deleting Rows and moving all rows together

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am needing to work out best way and quickest way to be able to achieve Deleting rows with an Y in column `A` and then moving all remaining rows up so no blank lines are left, as illustrated below.

```
Col A    Col B    Col C
Y        TOM      12
O        JOHN     11
Y        FRED     12
         TOM      12
O        JOHN     12
         TOM      12
Y        JOHN     12
Y        TOM      12
Y        JOHN     12
         FRED     10
         JOHN     12
```

Above is what the spread sheet looks like at first. I wish to be able to press a button or two and have it look like this:

```
Col A    Col B    Col C
O        JOHN     11
         TOM      12
O        JOHN     12
         TOM      12
         FRED     10
         JOHN     12
```

This is how I need it to look at end.

Hoping someone can help me out.

Kindest Regards
Natasha Willson

Comment: Have you thought of using [filters](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e)? Or do you really need to delete those rows?

Comment: Define a vba macro, then with **Alt-F8**, view the Macros dialogue and double click the deletion macro. Done. I will provide an answer with this macro altered for deletion as it was originally written to hide and unhide rows.

Comment: **#Natasha**, you have asked similar question just few days back,, check this link https://superuser.com/questions/1406892/delete-only-certain-rows/1406978#1406978  and there I've responded it with MACRO as solution. Therefore this one should be considered as DUPLICATE. So my suggestion is Delete this one to avoid Vote to Close .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete only certain Rows](https://superuser.com/questions/1406892/delete-only-certain-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following into a regular vba Module (Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic editor). After adding the code to an existing or new regular module, edit the `Const` properties as needed. The sheet name is the name appearing on the worksheet tab. To run the code, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd>, to open the Macro dialogue and double click (run) `Delete_Rows`.

**WARNING  Cannot undo deletions made by this macro and therefore the undo buffer is cleared.** In other words; this action will not appear in `Edit - Undo` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> will have no effect.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Delete_Rows()

  ' WARNING: Cannot undo deletions made by this macro and therefore
  '   the Undo Buffer Is Cleared. In other words; this action will
  '   not appear in "Edit - Undo" and Ctrl-z will have no effect.

  ' Delete Rows if row value in value_Column is delete_On_Value.
  ' value_Column must include start_on row number (e.g. A1 or C3)

  ' For speed, only process rows being used <= max_Row.
    Const valueColumn = "A2" ' Beginning Cell (row and column) to consider.
    Const maxRow = "" ' Last row number. If "", rest of rows in use.
    Const deleteOnValue = "Y"
    Const deletionSheetName = "Sheet12"
    Const deleteWarn = True

   '-------------------------------------------------------
   'All code from here on - no more user modifiable setting
   '

    Dim dSht As Worksheet
    Dim resetLastCell As Range
    Dim deleteRange As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rangeStart() As String
    Dim lastRow As String
    Dim tmpEnableEvents As Boolean
    Dim tmpScreenUpdating As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set dSht = Worksheets(deletionSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If dSht Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet Named: '" & deletionSheetName & "' not found.", _
            vbExclamation, "Deletion Macro - Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set resetLastCell = dSht.UsedRange ' call and discard to reset LastCell
    lastRow = dSht.Range(valueColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    If maxRow <> "" Then
       If Val(lastRow) > Val(maxRow) Then lastRow = maxRow
    End If
    rangeStart = Split(dSht.Range(valueColumn).Address(True, False), "$")
    If Val(rangeStart(1)) > Val(lastRow) Then
        If deleteWarn Then
            MsgBox "No used rows beginnig at start row '" & rangeStart(1) _
                & "'.", vbInformation, "Deletion Macro - Exiting"
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    tmpEnableEvents = Application.EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    tmpScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each r In dSht.Range(valueColumn & ":" & rangeStart(0) & lastRow)
        If IsEmpty(r) Then
        ElseIf CStr(r.Value2) = vbNullString Then
        ElseIf r = deleteOnValue Then
            If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleteRange = r
            Else
                Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
        If deleteWarn Then
            MsgBox "No rows to delete.", vbInformation, _
                "Deletion Macro - Exiting"
        End If
    ElseIf deleteWarn Then
        If 1 = MsgBox("Delete " & deleteRange.Count & " row(s) from '" & _
            deletionSheetName & "' tab?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, _
            "Deletion Macro - Confirmation") _
        Then
            deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Else ' no warning - just delete
        deleteRange.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = tmpScreenUpdating
    Application.EnableEvents = tmpEnableEvents
End Sub
```